# Parse Xml in GO for atttribute with ":" in tag

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I want to parse the attribute of an Xml file.
It works for any "normal" attributes like for instance `<application name="AppName">`

But I can't manage to retrieve the value of the attribute if it has a ":" in it., like `<application name:test="AppName">`

Here is the code that I am using to parse this :

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/xml"

type Application struct {
    Event Event `xml:"application"`
    Package   string    `xml:"package,attr"`
}

type Event struct {
    IsValid   string `xml:"test:isValid,attr"`
}

var doc = []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
    <application package="leNomDuPackage">
            <event test:isValid="true">
        </application>
</manifest>`)

func main() {
    application := Application{}
    xml.Unmarshal(doc, &application)

    fmt.Println("Application:  ", application)
    fmt.Println("isValid:", application.Event)
}
```

You can find it on the Golang playground as well : [https://play.golang.org/p/R6H80xPezhm

I want to retrieve the value of the `isValid` attribute.

At the moment, I have that error message and I can't manage to solve it.

> struct field tag `xml:"test\:isValid,attr` not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: bad syntax for struct tag value

I tried as well with the following value of

```
type Event struct {
    IsValid   string `xml:"test isValid,attr`
}
```

and

```
type Event struct {
    IsValid   string `xml:"test\:isValid,attr`
}
```

But it is not working as well.

Comment: You're missing the closing `"` in the tag, that's why the warning message from Go vet. Not that that will make it work or anything, it'll just get rid of the warning.

Comment: And to actually solve your issue, just remove the test prefix in the tag and have the Event field have a tag name `event`, same as the xml element, instead of `application`. E.g. (https://play.golang.org/p/cYDHw1LCklK)

Comment: The `XMLName` field is not required, that's not what makes it work. But the input should be valid XML.

Answer (score 8):

You can leave out the `"test:"` prefix in the tag definition. Just make sure your XML is valid, yours don't have a closing tag for `<event>` and has an unmatched closing tag `</manifest>`. You're also missing a closing quotation mark in the tag definition.

Model:

```
type Application struct {
    Event   Event  `xml:"event"`
    Package string `xml:"package,attr"`
}

type Event struct {
    IsValid string `xml:"isValid,attr"`
}
```

A valid XML example:

```
var doc = `
<application package="leNomDuPackage">
    <event test:isValid="true" />
</application>`
```

Code parsing it:

```
application := Application{}
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(doc), &application)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Application: %#v\n", application)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i8Bhz-PkkTo)):

```
Application: main.Application{Event:main.Event{IsValid:"true"},
    Package:"leNomDuPackage"}
```

Note that if you have multiple attributes with the same name but different prefixes, such as this example:

```
var doc = `
<application package="leNomDuPackage">
    <event test:isValid="true" test2:isValid="false" />
</application>`
```

Then you may add the namespace prefix in the tag value, separated by a space from the name, like this:

```
type Event struct {
    IsValid1 string `xml:"test isValid,attr"`
    IsValid2 string `xml:"test2 isValid,attr"`
}
```

Parsing code is the same. Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pVeSBjrJueI)):

```
Application: main.Application{Event:main.Event{IsValid1:"true", 
    IsValid2:"false"}, Package:"leNomDuPackage"}
```

Comment: If you really need the namespace defined just add it with a space after (so you could have two equaly named ones) like this

https://play.golang.org/p/HrPyhMJATwZ

Comment: @Kent Good idea, improved the answer with it.

Comment: Great that is working.
The xml wasn't good but I made it instead of the massive I must parse for my program. :-)
Thanks for pointing everything out by the way.