# Unmarshall xml containing ":" inside element tag Golang

Tags: xml, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have started parsing an xml file. However I am having trouble unmarshalling the following element:

```
    <Example>
    
        <xhtml:p>
            Some paragraph text
        </xhtml:p>
        <xhtml:div>
          Some div text
        </xhtml:div>
    </Example>
```

I want to extract text inside xhtml:p and xhtml:div

I have written the following code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Example struct{
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Example"`
    Paragraphs []string `xml:"xhtml:p"`
    Divs []string `xml:"xhtml:div"`
}

func main() {
    x:= []byte(`
      <Example>
        <pr>hello pr</pr>
        <xhtml:p>
            Some paragraph text
        </xhtml:p>
        <xhtml:div>
          Some div text
        </xhtml:div>
    </Example>
    `)

    var a Example
    xml.Unmarshal(x,&a)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

However when I print the `a` I get an empty slice for both `Paragraphs` and `Divs`.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave out the tag namespaces from the struct tags, and it'll work:

```
type Example struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"Example"`
    Paragraphs []string `xml:"p"`
    Divs       []string `xml:"div"`
}
```

With this change the output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bmtuMIUKK_p)):

```
{{ Example} [
            Some paragraph text
        ] [
          Some div text
        ]}
```

If you do want to specify the namespace, you have to add that to the struct tag spearated with a **space**, not a colon:

```
type Example struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"Example"`
    Paragraphs []string `xml:"xhtml p"`
    Divs       []string `xml:"xhtml div"`
}
```

This will give the same output. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IWtjt68JNh_J).

See related question: [Parse Xml in GO for atttribute with ":" in tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559581/parse-xml-in-go-for-atttribute-with-in-tag/51560007#51560007)

Comment: Thank you very much .It worked. Just out of curiosity `xhtml` is considered a namespace?

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Read this page for details: [XML Namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)